# Get list of online people from Facebook

Tags: php, c, facebook, list

Can I get a list of people that are online on Facebook?
For example, I am in a location and I want to get a list of people that are using Facebook at that time (are online) from a distance of, let's say, 50 meters. Is this possible?
Note: I notice that you can retrieve a list of online people that are in your friends list but what I want is to retrieve a list of online people in general, not only from the friends list.

Thank you!

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: Very, very not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly: NO

but there are workarounds like: make users login into your app with facebook, check their facebook online status and location, do your stuff based on that info.